# aligning the bottom bar elements

Tags: html, css

Hi I am trying to align the bottombar elements so that they are in 2 columns on the side of 102. I was wondering if there is a way to fix it as they are all floating on the right at the moment. I am a beginner html css programmer and I am not very experienced yet. Ill appreciate any help you can give me!

## CSS

```
/*bottom navbar*/
.bottomnav{
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(248, 138, 180);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.navbarlogo2{
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 10%;
  text-decoration: none;
}

/*bottombar*/
.nav {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
  }

  .left, .right {
    flex: 1;
  }
```

## HTML

```
<div class="bottomnav">
            <ul class="bottomlogo">
                <li class="navbarimg2"><img class="navbarlogo2" src="img/LOGO.png"></li>
            </ul>

            <div class='nav'>
                <div class='left'>
                  <ul>
                    <li>About Us</li>
                    <li>Affiliates</li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
                <div class='right'>
                  <ul>
                    <li>TOS</li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
        </div>
```

### END RESULT

[image]

### WANTED RESULT

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I made things like that. [CSS Grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) is one of the new HTML5 standard you should take a look. In your case, use a **grid** is better choice against **flex** because you're looking for a table-like structure.

I choosed to split your needs in 2 parts:

1. Center your logo
2. Make a 2 columns grid for your links

**Centering your logo**

We need to center an element and prevent it to interfere with our incoming links grid. So we'll set our container with a `position: relative` and place the `img` tag in `position: absolute`. Note the image's `top` `right` `bottom` `left` properties are now relative to the first parent positioned as `relative`.

And so we only need to make some simple maths. Note the **calc()** function, we don't want to center the top left corner of your logo but the center. So we need to remove the half of the defined logo's width.

```
navbarlogo2 {
  left: calc(50% - 60px);
}
```

**Make a 2 columns grid for your links**

In order make a grid, you have to display your container as grid and set its `grid-template-columns` to `1fr 1fr`. You can translate `fr` with the word fraction. So here, we're asking for a row split in 2 fractions.
Because we want a place for our logo, we're adding a gap (`grid-cap`) in out container to make some space between our 2 columns.
Learn more about the fr unit [here](https://css-tricks.com/introduction-fr-css-unit/).

```css
body {
  margin:0
}

.bottomnav {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(248, 138, 180);
  position: relative;
}

.navbarlogo2 {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 120px;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: absolute;
  filter: brightness(10);
  top: 15px;
  left: calc(50% - 60px) /*center top left corner then remove half logo width (120px)*/
}

/*bottombar*/
.nav {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 120px;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}
.nav ul {
  padding-left: 0;
}
.nav ul li {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 0;
}

.left,
.right {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="bottomnav">
  <div class="bottomlogo">
    <img class="navbarlogo2" src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-logo.svg">
  </div>

  <div class='nav'>
    <div class='left'>
      <ul>
        <li>About Us</li>
        <li>Affiliates</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class='right'>
      <ul>
        <li>TOS</li>
        <li>Fourth </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```